# Servlet ReqeustDispatcher forward to caller or previous servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, requestdispatcher

I have a SERVLET_A which forward to a  form(form.jsp page). The form submits to SERVLET_B. After values are inserted into database by SERVLET_B, I have to show the message "Values Inserted successfully" or error messages on the form". Now Here is where the problem lies.

I tried to make the requestdispatcher to forward to SERVLET_A to from SERVLET_B. But it does not work and also will not give me an error .

SERVLET_A -----------> FORM.jsp ----------->SERVLET_B----------------->SERVLET_A

My question is not how to get this done . because it works if I use sendRedirect instead of requestDispatcher.My questions are below

1. Is my understanding right that a servlet cannot forward back to the servlet that called it in the first place.?
2. I got this to work by setting my message in session and using sendredirect . Is this approach correct ?
3. I was told that it is always better to show form from a servlet. ( hides url and always use controller ) So that is why I have a servlet_A forwarding to form.jsp. I can access form.jsp directly but wanted to do it via a servlet so that is why SERVLET_A was created. 
   Coming from a php background this all seems to0 much to process a form.  Can anybody please let me know how forms are usually processesed in jsp MVC architecture .( without framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some problem with your code. It would have been better if you had posted the code. I will answer your questions one by one.
 1. Yes ServletB can again forward the request back to servletA I am
    posting sample code below

**ServletA GET method** urlpattern="sa"

```
RequestDispatcher view=request.getRequestDispatcher("form.jsp");
view.forward(request, response);
```

**form.jsp**

```
<body>
   <form action="./sb">
      <input type="text" name="fn" />
      <input type="submit"  value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <%= "fn : "+(String)session.getAttribute("fn") %>
</body>
```

**ServletB GET method** urlpattern="sb"

```
String fn = request.getParameter("fn");
request.getSession().setAttribute("fn",fn);
RequestDispatcher view=request.getRequestDispatcher("sa");
view.forward(request, response);
```

2.How to process forms using MVC without frameworks
    - Here V stand for view. Its the jsp or html page. You display everything in that. No processing should be done here.
    - C stands for Controller. Its your servlet. All data submitted in form are collected by servlet. No processing here also, just collect all data. Then create an object a plain Java class which is actually your M i.e. model class that will process data and return the result. In your case you should do the database part as a Model class specially using DAO design pattern
    - The servlet will take the result and pass it to a JSP or HTML page for showing it.
***What you should do***
As i understood from your approach its a wrong one. You should wither use Ajax or Asynchronous Processing of Request using Servlet 3.0. I mean that you should not do request forwarding back to ServletA i.e. to jsp after the processing is done. Instead you should generate an asynchronous request to ServletB for submitting data. Now when the result is generated ServletB sends the response as JSON string which is displayed by the javascript on your form.jsp page

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Sorry for not posting code .. I did not post the code since I got it to work using sendRedirect. I tried your code and it works for me . So now I know it is possible to forward back to caller servlet. that was the main point what I wanted to know.  Also thanks again for the mentioning Ajax and Asynchronous servlets, I shall look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Using a framework or not does not make much difference.

This is the way I do :

- use a servlet (method doGet) to pre-process request, get values from a database, etc., put values in request attributes and forward to a servlet for displaying HTML - ok, it is servlet A + form.jsp
- use a post to process the submitted form ; that way, you can use same servlet but doPost method and your `form` give : `<form method="POST">` with no action - using same url is largely matter of opinion ...
- at the end of doPost, redirect to servletA or another url (`response.senRedirect(...)`). That way, even if user reload its page or press back button of its browser, it will never post again, but simply get again the redirected URL.

Comment: Thanks for the "using the same servlet tip". I was thinking along the line .. but was unsure